# How can I make two Android devices show the same video simultaneously?

Tags: video, streaming

I would like to attach two Android tablets to the back of my car head rests so that my two children can watch films on long journeys.

I want them to be watching the exact same video at the same time, and I want them to be as in sync as possible, because the sound will be played over the car's speakers.

I am open to any solution: whether it's having a separate machine as a streaming server running Windows, Linux, or another Android tablet. Another solution might be that the two devices have both have the files on them, but control data is being sent from one device to another - master/slave style. In a truly ideal world, it would be controllable by a device by someone sitting in the front, but that's a nice to have.

My question is - are there any apps that allow any of these scenarios? I have been looking for about three hours myself and haven't found anything.

nb: Pressing play simultaneously on the two devices is not a viable option, and neither is getting the children to wear headphones.

Comment: Sounds like it would be far easier to just use one tablet and hang it between the two headrests?

Comment: i've considered that, but it would be a) difficult - how would one physically hang a tablet between two seats?, b) dangerous - a suspended tablet could be lethal in the event of a collision.

Comment: A) My brother's done this in his car with a Nexus 7, buy a protective case that you keep on while using the device, sew two loops to the top two corners, hook them round the head-rest pillars, done. Most things in the car, including the backs of seats can be lethal in the event of a collision, but you're entitled to make your own choice where you place those risks, so fair enough.

Comment: What about android as device streaming video, then LCD screens/monitors for the headrests? Seems like a easier solution.

Comment: i am currently testing Syncplay for VLC.  seems like it would work.  if it does, i will post a step by step.  http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Syncplay+interface+module+for+VLC?content=159160

Comment: Have you thought of using Miracast? I'm about to take on a project to do this with a pair of budget tablets... Miracast would allow for master slave. All the content would be on one device and cast to the other. Plus the master device could connect to the car Bluetooth system to provide the audio. That's my 'theory' anyway.

Answer (score 2):

VLC works perfectly for me :)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.codejugglers.android.vlchd&hl=en

Did you tried this link? It uses Moboplayer and ES file Explorer.
http://apcmag.com/how-to-stream-video-to-an-android-device.htm

Davy

Comment: Anybody had this work? Is this a working solution?

Comment: would you mind expounding on HOW to use VLCHD remote to synchronize videos?  as is, this is more of a comment than  a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

GarethD I know that your original question was posted over five years ago but, I have been looking for same solution and so far I have found just one that works for me.
You need to download two apps.
No ROOT required!
On master device install: [Mirror](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.mirror)
On slave device install:[AllCast Receiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast.receiver)
That is pretty much all. Start AllCast Receiver on slave, then start Mirror on master, choose receiving device from the list and you should see the master screen on slave device. Exit the app on master, choose your video player, start playback, sit back and relax ;)
I have master device connected to car stereo so audio is played over the car's speakers.
:NOTE:
1. Both devices have to be connected to same network for this to work.
2. Mirror app in free edition is casting watermark. If you watch films with black bars at top and bottom this is not too obtrusive. It will get in the way for full screen videos. Or you can just upgrade to the full version.

Answer (score 1):

It took me ages to work this out, but to play one movie in sync on two tablets download an app called gplayer. After that:

1. hold down on video you want to play and click "add into share list"
2. go across to share and select the second device also do this on the second device but obviously select the the other device
3. on the second device click the shared video and let it download.
4. go it setting from the drop down menu on the right scroll down to the "group media sharing settings" and tuck the box that says "enable group media sharing  service" do this on both devices
5. ensure both screens are on and in the share section and open on either device and it should play in sync on both screens

Comment: Colin, could you please [edit] your post and include a link to the gplayer app? Do you mean [GPlayer](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.PopupVideo)?

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.mirrorop.com does what you need.

check this up.

http://clintonmann.com/blog/software-for-mirroring-a-display-across-multiple-android-devices/

Answer (score -1):

You can use upnp monkey for android. it can stream to multiple devices

Comment: That might be an option, if one can find the suggested app. Could you please [edit] your answer and include a link to it? Thanks! :)